# Handling lost connection with client inside a .NET webservice - possible?

Tags: .net, web-services, error-handling

I have written a webservice which calls a procedure in database and returns this procedure's results as a DataSet. Is there any way to know (inside this webservice) if the connection with client was lost while returning data? I'd like to handle this situation rolling back any changes i made to my db. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In the client enclose the code where the webservice call is made  inside a try-catch block and do whatever required on exception inside the catch block.

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to handle such exception in my webservice, not in client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question you want to ensure that your client gets back the data from your service as only in that case you want to commit some changes to the database. That is possible only if client initiates distributed transaction, your service joins the transaction and then when client receives data he commits the transaction.

This is supported in WCF ([transaction flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116.aspx)). ASMX web services doesn't support this interaction - in such case [you must manually control MSDTC transaction](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/09db9bf1-eda6-4525-8879-c2a40789b239).